# Turn off the second monitor with a button click

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Is there a batch file or something that I can use to quickly turn off one monitor in my dual monitor setup?

Currently, I do this by using `Win + P` and then selecting the appropriate options. I would prefer to do all this in a single step.

For example, I double click the `.bat` file and it automatically toggles the other monitor on or off.

If that's not possible. Can I somehow create a shortcut key combination where both these actions take place with a single keystroke like `Ctrl + Alt + P` etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a faster way than the power button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many programs that can do this.

To limit it to freeware, nirsoft makes great tools for batch scripts and system management.

One tool they got that just seems specifically adressing your issue is this one:
[Multi Monitor Tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/turn-off-monitor.html).

This can be used from the GUI to turn monitors on or off, switch configuration etc, but it also has command line switches so you can implement this in your batch file.

Comment: Nir Sofer is a programming hero of mine. Every utility he does is really small in filesize, and wireless network watcher is hands down the best network scanner available.